# How to enable the user flag 'User must change password at next logon' for a local windows user?

Tags: windows, powershell

I wanted to enable the userflag 'User must change password at next logon' through powershell scripts. 
For the flag Account is disable, I did the following :

```
$user=[ADSI]'WinNT://localhost/account23';
$user.userflags = 2;
$user.setinfo();
```

Is it possible to add the user flag for 'User must change password at next logon' in the similar way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to enable the flag 'User muat change password at next logon' through the following :

```
$user.passwordExpired = 1;
$user.setinfo();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's a calculated value,so you can't set it directly, but if you set the pwdLastSet value to 0 it should have the same effect:

```
$user.pwdLastSet = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$username = "enter your local user name here";
$user=[ADSI]"WinNT://localhost/$username";
$user.userflags = 2;
$user.setinfo();
```

Comment: Thanks dudes It works well for local user in windows server data center 2019 Edition

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From Review.